# CSS3 filter not working in Edge

Tags: css, filter, microsoft-edge

Checkout this page http://www.urbansportsleague.org/gallery
In edge its showing black space on hover.

Here is the code below you may check and let me know.

Thanks in Advance.

```css
.gallery-img {

  height: 250px;

  padding: 10px;

  -webkit-filter: blur(0.5px);

}

.gallery-img>img {

  max-height: 200px;

  width: auto;

  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);

}

.gallery-img>img:hover {

  -webkit-filter: contrast(150%);

  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

  filter: contrast(150%);

}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6  gallery-img">
  <img class="img img-thumbnail" src="http://www.urbansportsleague.org/assets/gallery/1.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6  gallery-img">
  <img class="img img-thumbnail" src="http://www.urbansportsleague.org/assets/gallery/2.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: It is because it is not supported http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Comment: http://www.unlockwindows.com/how-to-enable-css3-filters-in-microsoft-edge/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS filters are supported by Edge according to its own documentation at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/. The support has been there since the November 2015 update.

Interestingly with your code snippet the filter works for me, but on http://www.urbansportsleague.org/gallery it does not work if I don't remove the `-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);` rule on `.gallery-img > img`. Could it be that Edge is a bit buggy when these things are combined? And yes, Edge also reads that `-webkit-transform` because many websites forget to include the equivalent `transform` rule.

I also tried to remove other CSS that shouldn't affect the behavior of the filter. After removing just Bootstrap and backgrounds, I got the page into an otherwise broken state where the filter worked correctly most of the time. Still sometimes the image just disappeared. Sometimes the image disappeared just after the filter had been applied to the image for a fraction of a second.